# Jquery group tr elements with same class and put header

Tags: jquery, html-table, grouping

I have a table structure as below, how can I group the same class table rows and insert a new table row containing the data title for the same elements before the first table row of the same class tr:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="section section_2" data-title="Data Title 2">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section section_2" data-title="Data Title 2">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section section_1" data-title="Data Title 1">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section section_3" data-title="Data Title 3">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section section_3" data-title="Data Title 3">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So the new structured table will look like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td colspan="3">Data Title 2</td></tr>
        <tr class="section section_2" data-title="Data Title 2">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section section_2" data-title="Data Title 2">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3">Data Title 1</td></tr>
        <tr class="section section_1" data-title="Data Title 1">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3">Data Title 3</td></tr>
        <tr class="section section_3" data-title="Data Title 3">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section section_3" data-title="Data Title 3">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your html sample (1st one)

```
var titles =[] ;
$.each ($('tr.section'), function (index, elt) {
    var title =$(elt).attr ('data-title') ;
    if ( $.inArray (title, titles) == -1 )
        $('<tr><td colspan="3">' + title + '</td></tr>').insertBefore ($(elt)) ;
    titles.push (title) ;
}) ;
```

you'll get the 2nd sample

Comment: Also how can I add different background color for `<tr><td colspan="3">Data Title 3</td></tr>` so it can be identified as header? @cyrille